# drawing with <canvas> in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas, server-side-rendering, procedural-generation

1. I have a node server that checks twitter user @example every 24 hours;

1a. if there are no new tweets then nothing happens.

1b. if there *are* new tweets then for each tweet I want to draw an image in canvas.

2. Once the new image is drawn (based on instructions in the tweet) the app should upload the new image to my @example_new twitter handle.

I have the node server listening. I also have the drawing application working locally - you can feed in a url param " localhost:123/?tweet=instructions from tweet " but just realized I can't 'connect' them easily. 
Ideally there's no browser, the node app listens to a twitter handle, creates an image and uploads to twitter with no other user interaction. 
Since node doesn't have a DOM i'm not sure how to do this.

NOTE:I looked into drawing with ImageMagick but don't think it'll work in this instance, would really like to try to implement using the Canvas API before I explore that.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: found a package here: https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas

node-canvas provides a virtual canvas object that you can draw to, then you can pass this virtual object to the browser or write it to a file etc.

It worked perfectly!

Comment: Can you explain how to pass the object from node.js to browser? If you give me an example it would be great.